# Django Deferred Attribute operand error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute'
```

in Django, when I am trying to use two variables as such:

```
def MakeCalcs(a,b):
    varc = a*b
    return varC
```

I think that this originates from the fact that when the model fields are being populated in sequence (i.e., `a` and `b` are being populated after the model already exits).

My question is how do I use those model fields?  is there some way to turn a deferred attribute into one that you can apply operations to?

Edit: Is there a way to prevent these from being "deferred" in the first place? i.e., a way to refresh the model?

Comment: Why are you deferring the fields in the first place?

Comment: The model has about 40 different fields on it and I am populating it stepwise... first form populates the things like project name, project type, project budget,etc.  Second form captures information about technical details... 3rd form captures information about timeline, etc.  

However, I use them all together at some point, so have them in one model.  Hence the deferral issue.  Also, there are times where IF project type == X, then only fill out this DB field, etc.